# Variable not storing as requested

Tags: c++, loops, int, increment

Here is my code:

```
point * findLongPaths(point * points, double threshold_distance) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    int locationToStore = 0;
    int pointsAboveThreshold = countPointsAboveThreshold(points, threshold_distance);
    //int totalPoint = totalPoints(points);

    point * pointsByThreshold = new point[pointsAboveThreshold];
    pointValues * pointsToCalculate = new pointValues[pointsAboveThreshold];
    //pointValues pointsToCalculate[pointsAboveThreshold];
    //point orderedPoints[pointsAboveThreshold];

    while (points[i].end != true && i < pointsAboveThreshold) {
        point pointOne = points[i];
        point pointTwo = points[i + 1];

        //Check to see if the distance is greater than the threshold, if it is store in an array of pointValues
        double distance = distanceBetweenTwoPoints(pointOne, pointTwo);
        if (distance > threshold_distance) {
            pointsToCalculate[i].originalLocation = i;
            pointsToCalculate[i].distance = distance;
            pointsToCalculate[i].final = pointTwo;
            pointsToCalculate[i].stored = false;

            //If the final point has been calculated, break the loop
            if (pointTwo.end == true) {
                pointsToCalculate[i].end = true;
                break;
            } else {
                pointsToCalculate[i].end = false;
                i++;
                continue;
            }
        } 
    }

    if (points[0].end == true && pointsAboveThreshold == 0) {
        point emptyPoint;
        emptyPoint.x = 0.0;
        emptyPoint.y = 0.0;
        emptyPoint.end = true;

        pointsByThreshold[0] = emptyPoint;
        return pointsByThreshold;
    }

    //Find the point with the lowest distance
    i = 1;
    //double lowest = 0.0;

    //EDITED
    pointValues pointWithLowest;
    pointWithLowest = pointsToCalculate[0];
    while (pointsToCalculate[i].end != true) {
        for (int j = 0; pointsToCalculate[j].end != true; j++) {
            if (pointsToCalculate[j].stored == true) {
                j++;
                continue;
            } else {
                if (pointsToCalculate[j].distance < pointWithLowest.distance) {
                    pointWithLowest = pointsToCalculate[j];
                    j++;
                    continue;
                } else if (pointsToCalculate[j].distance == pointWithLowest.distance) {
                    if (pointWithLowest.originalLocation > pointsToCalculate[j].originalLocation) {
                        pointWithLowest = pointsToCalculate[j];
                        j++;
                        continue;
                    }
                } else {
                    pointWithLowest.stored = true;
                    pointsByThreshold[locationToStore] = pointWithLowest.final;
                    locationToStore++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    delete[] pointsToCalculate;
    return pointsByThreshold;
}
```

For some weird reason when I go to store `i` in the line `pointsToCalculate[i].originalLocation = i;`, it's always storing as 0. I have ran breakpoints over it and it shows that the value of `i` was incremented in the while loop but it's still storing `originalLocation` to 0. When I check the values in runtime, it shows that the `i` in `pointsToCalculate[i] is`1`or`2`, depends on how many times I have ran through the loop and it also shows that`= i;`is also`1`or`2` depending on the loop.

Anyone know why this is? It's for an assignment that's due in a few hours and I've been working on it for a very long time. Still, just can't figure it out.

Thanks,
Brandon

Comment: please don't post code with commented out sections

Comment: is `pointTwo.end` ever equal to false?

Comment: Sorry, Mitch I deleted the majority of it. Yeah, it's for an assignment and we can be guaranteed that pointTwo.end will always equal false unless it's the final point in the array. By checking it against the code the lecturer will be testing it against, how can I set a default value for points? Maybe that will fix the problem. He uses this line to test it `point p[3] = {{0,0}, {0,3}, {0,1, true}};
 point longest[2] = {{0,1}, {0,3,true}};
 BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(calculateLineLength(p), 5);`

Comment: Brandon, the issue with the code snippet you have given in your comment is that it won't work. Assuming that your point struct has three attributes `{num, num, boolean}`, your values `{{0,0}, {0,3}.... {0,1}` wont fly because you would need `{{0,0,false}, {0,3,false}` etc to make the declaration valid.

Comment: @Brandon: In your example, I see some true's. Are you sure it is being set to false?

Comment: That's what I was just looking at but I'm not allowed to change the line of code because it's the code that the lecturer will be using to test against it. In saying that, is there anyway to set the default value of a point `{{int, int}} would become {{int, int, false}}?

Comment: @Brandon - Yes, depending on how the class is declared. There could be an overloaded constructer that simply takes two arguments. As for your code, I'm not sure what's wrong, but remove all the extraneous code and just test the `findLongPaths` method. See if the error occurs because of the method, or because of something that happens outside of the method.

Comment: Here is my typedef: `typedef struct {
    unsigned int originalLocation;
    double distance;
    point final;
    bool stored;
    bool end;
} pointValues;` It should, hopefully work if I set the default value of end to false. But how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you using breakpoints and debug info as your sole means of viewing that variable?  And is the build in Debug mode?  I had a similar situation to yours, and it was caused by trying to view the debug info on a Release build.

Comment: @BlackJack and @Brandon: what is going on here?  The claim that "your values {{0,0}, {0,3}.... {0,1} wont fly because you would need {{0,0,false}, {0,3,false} etc to make the declaration valid" is false, assuming that `point` is a plain struct which can be initialized in aggregate.  It doesn't have anything to do with a "two argument constructor" if no constructor is being used--it's just plain C basically.  And yes, if you initialize a three-element struct with just two elements (like {1,2}), the third element will be default-initialized (i.e. it will be zero, or false).

Answer (score 1):

if `distance <= threshold_distance`,the `i` won't increment, and while loop will loop forerver